# No setter for property isClustered in RAMJobStore Quartz 2.3

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, quartz

I'm creating a `Job` in Quartz 2.3.0, I researched that to create a `Job` and configure it for a multi-instance environment in production, it had to be defined in the `quartz.properties` file, which is inside in the jar.

This is my `quartz.properties` file:

```
# Default Properties file for use by StdSchedulerFactory
# to create a Quartz Scheduler Instance, if a different
# properties file is not explicitly specified.

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export: false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy: false
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction: false
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: AUTO

org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class: org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered : true
```

And these are my java classes `TestPlugin`:

```
public class TestPlugin implements PlugIn {
    private static Scheduler scheduler;

    public TestPlugin() {
        super();
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void init(ActionServlet arg0, ModuleConfig arg1) throws ServletException {
        try {
            JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(TestDemonio.class).withIdentity(new JobKey("jobs", "group1")).build();//.withIdentity("anyJobName", "group1").build();
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                    .newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity("anyTriggerName", "group1")
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/59 * * ? * * *"))//0/5 * * * * ?
                    .build();

            Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
            scheduler.start();
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My `TestDemon` class:

```
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class TestDemon implements Job {

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            System.out.println("PRINT JOB MESSAGE");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

But I'm getting the `SchedulerException`:

> `JobStore` class '`org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore`' props could not be
>   configured. [See nested exception: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`: No
>   setter for property '`isClustered`']

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to enable clustering for RAMJobStore because the quartz-scheduler does clustering using the database and in case of RAMJobStore the jobs are created in memory and cannot be shared across processes.

```
Clustering currently works with the JDBC-Jobstore (JobStoreTX or JobStoreCMT) and the TerracottaJobStore. Features include load-balancing and job fail-over (if the JobDetail’s “request recovery” flag is set to true).
```

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-11.html